# Tensorflow: How to have n number of image inputs to determine 1 output: handwriting data matching

Tags: python, tensorflow, handwriting-recognition

I'm trying to develop a model to tell you if a handwriting sample matches the other samples provided which are all from a single individual. I have an example using one image to match the other, but I'm not quite sure how to deal with allowing a user to upload n number of handwriting samples. Can anyone provide some insights on using n number of image inputs to come up with a 0 / 1 classification?

Comment: uploading, are you using any web framework, ie. flask?

Comment: There is multiple ways to handle this, but I don't think that question belongs to StackOverflow. I suggest that you try on the [Data Science Stack Exchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Lescurel I'll make sure to go there next time, thank you for that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, we can use a Siamese Neural Network to match a given signature with N other images of the same signature ( provided by the user ). A Siamese Neural network takes in two images and outputs a similarity score in [ 0, 1 ] for the given pair of images.

So we train a Siamese Neural Network on various pairs of images which may contain two signatures from a person or two different signatures. For a pair in which both the signatures belong to the same person, we assign a label of 1 and for other cases, we assign a label of 0. It could be thought of as a binary classification problem where we have two classes "similar" and "not similar".

Refer to these blogs to create a Siamese CNN ( the one with convolutional layers as inputs to the model are images ),

- [A friendly introduction to Siamese Networks](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-friendly-introduction-to-siamese-networks-85ab17522942)
- [One Shot Learning with Siamese Networks using Keras](https://towardsdatascience.com/one-shot-learning-with-siamese-networks-using-keras-17f34e75bb3d)